# Analyzing c# project using travis and sonarcloud gives "no lines of code"

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, travis-ci, sonarcloud

I've been struggling with this issue for a few days now and I can't seem to pinpoint what I'm doing wrong.

I've been trying to analyze a c# project that is build with [travis CI](https://travis-ci.org) and analyzed in [sonarcloud](https://sonarcloud.io/).

I've set up travis (see: https://travis-ci.org/ShiveringSquirrel/heroes-app-webapi) to build and it seems to work fine.

### Configuration

See [.travis.yml](https://github.com/ShiveringSquirrel/heroes-app-webapi/blob/master/.travis.yml)

```
language: csharp
solution: heroes-app-webapi.sln
dist: trusty
sudo: required

mono:
  - latest

install:
  - nuget restore heroes-app-webapi.sln
  - nuget install NUnit.Console -Version 3.9.0 -OutputDirectory testrunner

addons:
  sonarcloud:
    organization: "shiveringsquirrel-github"
    token:
      secure: $SONAR_TOKEN

script:
  - msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /target:rebuild heroes-app-webapi.sln
  - mono ./testrunner/NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.9.0/tools/nunit3-console.exe ./heroes-app-webapi.Tests/bin/Release/heroes-app-webapi.Tests.dll
  - sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER

cache:
  directories:
    - '$HOME/.sonar/cache'

git:
  clone: true
  quiet: false
  depth: false
  submodules: true

# blocklist
branches:
  except:
  - legacy
  - experimental

# safelist
branches:
  only:
  - master
  - stable
```

See [sonar-project.properties](https://github.com/ShiveringSquirrel/heroes-app-webapi/blob/master/sonar-project.properties)

```
sonar.projectKey=ShiveringSquirrel_heroes-app-webapi
sonar.projectName=heroes-app-webapi
#sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.projectDescription=The backend API for the Heroes test application

sonar.links.homepage=https://github.com/ShiveringSquirrel/heroes-app-webapi
sonar.links.ci=https://travis-ci.org/ShiveringSquirrel/heroes-app-webapi
sonar.links.scm=https://github.com/ShiveringSquirrel/heroes-app-webapi
sonar.links.issue=https://github.com/ShiveringSquirrel/heroes-app-webapi/issues

#sonar.sources=.
#sonar.sources=src/main
#sonar.tests=src/test
sonar.sources=heroes-app-webapi
sonar.tests=heroes-app-webapi.Tests

sonar.scm.provider=git
sonar.scm.forceReloadAll=true

sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.testProjectPattern=*.Test
sonar.language=cs
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.verbose=true
sonar.exclusions=**/*.xml
sonar.inclusions=**/*.cs

sonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths=TestResult.xml
```

### Building

The full build log for travis: [See full build log](https://travis-ci.org/ShiveringSquirrel/heroes-app-webapi)

Some relevant snippets form the log:

```
$ mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 5.20.1.19 (tarball Thu Apr 11 09:05:42 UTC 2019)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    Interpreter:   yes
    LLVM:          yes(600)
    Suspend:       hybrid
    GC:            sgen (concurrent by default)
$ msbuild /version
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.0.0.0 for Mono
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Building with msbuild

```
$ msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /target:rebuild heroes-app-webapi.sln
....
    302 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:06.94
The command "msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /target:rebuild heroes-app-webapi.sln" exited with 0.
```

Unit testing

```
$ mono ./testrunner/NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.9.0/tools/nunit3-console.exe ./heroes-app-webapi.Tests/bin/Release/heroes-app-webapi.Tests.dll
....
Test Run Summary
  Overall result: Passed
  Test Count: 25, Passed: 25, Failed: 0, Warnings: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Skipped: 0
  Start time: 2019-07-14 21:00:34Z
    End time: 2019-07-14 21:00:36Z
    Duration: 2.559 seconds
Results (nunit3) saved as TestResult.xml
The command "mono ./testrunner/NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.9.0/tools/nunit3-console.exe ./heroes-app-webapi.Tests/bin/Release/heroes-app-webapi.Tests.dll" exited with 0.
```

Sonar-scanner

```
$ sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER
...
21:00:40.716 DEBUG: Plugins:
...
21:00:40.717 DEBUG:   * SonarC# 7.15.0.8572 (csharp)
...
21:00:46.518 DEBUG: 77 non excluded files in this Git repository
21:00:46.541 DEBUG: 'heroes-app-webapi/Global.asax.cs' indexed with language 'cs'
21:00:46.549 DEBUG: 'heroes-app-webapi/Attributes/JwtAuthenticationAttribute.cs' indexed with language 'cs'
...
21:00:46.802 INFO: 30 files indexed
21:00:46.803 INFO: 0 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
21:00:46.804 INFO: 0 files ignored because of scm ignore settings
21:00:46.805 INFO: Quality profile for cs: Sonar way
21:00:46.806 INFO: ------------- Run sensors on module heroes-app-webapi
...
21:00:51.019 INFO: Sensor C# Properties [csharp]
21:00:51.021 WARN: No Roslyn issues report found for this project.
...
21:00:51.052 INFO: Sensor C# Unit Test Results Import [csharp]
21:00:51.054 INFO: Parsing the NUnit Test Results file /home/travis/build/ShiveringSquirrel/heroes-app-webapi/./TestResult.xml
...
21:00:51.713 INFO: SCM provider for this project is: git
21:00:51.715 INFO: 27 files to be analyzed
...
21:00:52.065 INFO: 27/27 files analyzed
21:00:52.068 INFO: Calculating CPD for 0 files
21:00:52.078 INFO: CPD calculation finished
21:00:52.235 INFO: Analysis report generated in 151ms, dir size=190 KB
21:00:52.288 INFO: Analysis report compressed in 51ms, zip size=56 KB
21:00:52.289 INFO: Analysis report generated in /home/travis/build/ShiveringSquirrel/heroes-app-webapi/.scannerwork/scanner-report
21:00:52.290 DEBUG: Upload report
21:00:52.630 DEBUG: POST 200 https://sonarcloud.io/api/ce/submit?organization=shiveringsquirrel-github&projectKey=ShiveringSquirrel_heroes-app-webapi&projectName=heroes-app-webapi | time=338ms
21:00:52.633 INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 343ms
21:00:52.637 INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse https://sonarcloud.io/dashboard?id=ShiveringSquirrel_heroes-app-webapi
21:00:52.637 INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
21:00:52.639 INFO: More about the report processing at https://sonarcloud.io/api/ce/task?id=AWvySdH4BABcSdLoSktk
21:00:52.640 DEBUG: Report metadata written to /home/travis/build/ShiveringSquirrel/heroes-app-webapi/.scannerwork/report-task.txt
21:00:52.646 DEBUG: Post-jobs : 
21:00:52.650 INFO: Analysis total time: 11.885 s
21:00:52.652 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
21:00:52.656 INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
21:00:52.658 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
21:00:52.662 INFO: Total time: 15.232s
21:00:52.860 INFO: Final Memory: 34M/349M
21:00:52.860 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
21:00:52.860 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
21:00:52.860 DEBUG: Execution stop
The command "sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER" exited with 0.
```

So to me it all looks pretty good, only in sonarcloud.io (https://sonarcloud.io/dashboard?id=ShiveringSquirrel_heroes-app-webapi) I see nothing is analyzed.

Not even lines of code, it did update my build number and other settings. But no report or analysis. If I look at the background task:

```
21:00:52.639 INFO: More about the report processing at https://sonarcloud.io/api/ce/task?id=AWvySdH4BABcSdLoSktk
```

It says "success". The other thing I've tried to investigate is the one warning I have:

```
21:00:51.021 WARN: No Roslyn issues report found for this project.
```

But it seems to me from the log that everything is analyzed properly...
Any ideas?

Comment: As of today, I can see code on the linked SonarCloud project. Does that mean you were able to resolve the issue? Out of curiosity, what was the problem, and how did you fix it?

Comment: Hi Janos, Sadly no I wasn't, I never got it to work or figured out what was wrong. I switched to [appveyor](https://www.appveyor.com/) which did work for me. You can see that in the git projects I removed the travis.yml and added an appveyor.yml. That is the reason you see data in sonarcloud.